# Writing and reading ListMultimap<Object, Object> to file using Properties

Tags: java, json, properties, guava, multimap

How can I write and read ListMultimap to file using Properties?

I have an `index` as follows:

```
ListMultimap<Object, Object> index = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

and writing `index` to file using `Properties` as follows:

```
writeIndexToFile(ListMultimap<Object, Object> listMultimap, String fileName) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties = MapUtils.toProperties(toMap(listMultimap));
    properties.store(new FileOutputStream(fileName),null);
}
```

where, `toMap()` method is:

```
Map<Object, Object> toMap(ListMultimap<Object, Object> multiMap) {
    if (multiMap == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    for (Object key : multiMap.keySet()) {
        map.put(key, multiMap.get(key));
    }
    return map;
}
```

After running this code, I found the output file is empty. Why nothing is getting written into file?

in above code I cannot call directly as:

MapUtils.toProperties(listMultimap);

because `listMultimap` is not of type `Map`. So I converted it to `Map` using method `toMap()`. But still it seems that Properties is unable to get map correctly.

**Note:**

I tried printing `listMultimap` by converting it to JSON using Gson, but this also failed to convert to string. No Exception occured, but it returned empty string. Actual `listMultimap`  is something like:

[image: listMultiMap]

where, `index == listMultimap`.

I'm not getting where am I going wrong.

Comment: Your transformation code will not work: a `ListMultimap`'s `.get()` method return a `List<Object>`.

Comment: Then is there any way to get rid of this? When I printed Class of result from `get()`, it gave me `class com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap$RandomAccessWrappedList`.

Comment: The problem you have is that a key can be mapped to multiple values in a `ListMultimap`, how do you want to "map" it into a "normal" map?

Comment: Yah, I can see that problem. But then is there any other way by which I can write `ListMultimap` to file and read it back?

Comment: I have even tried with `listMultimap.asMap()` to convert to `Map`. Still this has not written to file using `Properties`.

Comment: How do you imagine writing a list to properties? I.e. `key = value` supports only one value for key, so it's difficult to say what you are trying to achieve. Also, if you used generics properluy, you would see what is the problem with your current code.

Comment: Most ListMultimap implementations implement Serializable.  Why not use that?