# Writing and reading ListMultimap<Object, Object> in file

Tags: java, file-io, guava, multimap

I tried writing `ListMultimap` to file using `Properties`, but it seems impossible, refer to question [Writing and reading ListMultimap to file using Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697974/writing-and-reading-listmultimapobject-object-to-file-using-properties).

Going ahead, if using `Properties` to store `ListMultimap` is not correct way, how can we store `ListMultimap` into a file? And how can we read back from file?

e.g. lets say I have:

```
ListMultimap<Object, Object> index = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

How can I write methods to write this `ListMultimap` to file and read back from file:

```
writeToFile(ListMultimap multiMap, String filePath){
    //??
}

ListMultimap readFromFile(String filePath){
    ListMultimap multiMap;
    //multiMap = read from file
    return multiMap;
}
```

Comment: Is it an option to serialize/deserialize the object? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide how you will represent each object in the file.  For example, if your `ListMultimap` contained `String`s you could simply write the string value but if you're dealing with complex objects you need to produce a representation of those object as a `byte[]`, which if you want to use `Properties` should then be Base64 encoded.

The basic read method should be something like:

```
public ListMultimap<Object, Object> read(InputStream in) throws IOException
{
  ListMultimap<Object, Object> index = ArrayListMultimap.create();

  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.load(in);

  for (Object serializedKey : properties.keySet())  
  {
    String deserializedKey = deserialize(serializedKey);
    String values = properties.get(serializedKey);

    for (String value : values.split(",")) 
    {
      index.put(deserializedKey, deserialize(value)); 
    }
  }

  return index;
}
```

And the write method this:

```
public void write(ListMultimap<Object, Object> index, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
  Properties properties = new Properties();

  for (Object key : index.keySet())
  {
    StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();

    for (Object value = index.get(key))
    {
      values.append(serailize(value)).append(",");
    } 

    properties.setProperty(serailize(key), values.subString(0, values.length - 1));
  }

  properties.store(out, "saving");
}
```

This example makes use of `serialize` and `deserialize` methods that you'll need to define according to your requirements but the signatures are:

```
public String serialize(Object object)
```

and

```
public Object deserialize(String s)
```

Comment: to serialize and deserialize one can refer to this thread: [how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134492/how-to-serialize-an-object-into-a-string) .

Comment: be careful using Java serialization - if your class is modified after the file is written (classes do tend to change over time) and then try to read it the deserialization will fail.  It's worth reading what Joshua Bloch has to say on this in Effective Java - http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PP1&dq=effective+java&pg=PA289